# How to add selected combobox item to a datatable?

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I have a DataGridView that uses a DataTable as its DataSource, I then added a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to the DataGridView. Everything is displayed fine up to this point. However, when the user selects an item from the combobox column, the selected item is not included in the DataSource of the DataGridView. Is there a way I can include the selected item into the DataSource other than looping through the DataGridView?

```
dgvNewChargesChild.DataSource = null;

//dt is some DataTable
dgvNewChargesChild.DataSource = dt;

//create a combobox column
DataTable cbDT = new DataTable();
cbDT.Columns.Add("ChargeType", typeof(string));
cbDT.Columns.Add("ChargeTypeID", typeof(string));
cbDT.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Storage", "1" });
cbDT.Rows.Add(new object[] { "BankService", "2" });

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cbCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
cbCol.ValueMember = "ChargeTypeID";
cbCol.DisplayMember = "ChargeType";
cbCol.DataSource = cbDT;

//add combobox column to the datagridview
dgvNewChargesChild.Columns.AddRange(cbCol);

//get the datasource of the datagridview after user makes a selection from the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
DataTable newDT = (DataTable) dgvNewChargesChild.DataSource;

//this newDT does not include the selected item from the combobox.
```

Comment: is this WPF or winform or what?

Comment: @currarpickt I forgot to mention. It's winform.